# How to import a Resource file within Test cases in Robot Framework?

Tags: robotframework

I have 2 Testcases within a Robot suite. This suite is like the **Initialization Suite** which has a dependency on an underlying framework(UF).

UF has different folder structure for the main **Initialization Suite**, **Functional Suites** and few other tools and calls them with separate robot commands. So I cannot store variables with **Set Global Variables** during initialization but have to create resource files which I will import in **Functional Suites**.

TC1: Parses a json file and creates a **variables.txt** file.

TC2: Uses few variables stored in **variables.txt** and logs into server the gets the node details and stores in **hostname.txt**

- Is there a way to import/source the **variables.txt** within TC2 ?
- Looking for this implementation, as there are Common User Keywords(CUKW) which will also need this **variables.txt**. As this is dynamically generated I cannot define it as **Resource** in Settings section in CUKW.

New to Robot framework, Apologies for any misunderstanding. Any better implementation suggestions are most welcome.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [import resource](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Import%20Resource) keyword.

> Imports a resource file with the given path.
>
> Resources imported with this keyword are set into the test suite scope similarly when importing them in the Setting table using the Resource setting.

Comment: Thanks @BryanOakley
Was searching for this keyword.